# create new columns based on the column names in tidyverse

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, r-colnames

My data set has columns where the variable categories are mentioned, for eg:
column name is "Shrawan 2071 -Dog Bite". Here "Shrawan" is the month "2071" is a year and "-Dog Bite" is the type of bite. Similarly, I have another column "Bhadra 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite" where "Bhadra"  is the month, "2071" is the year and "Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite" is the type of bite, and so on. In this way, I have 12 different month categories, 2 types of bite and 10-year data. How do I separate these column names as categories in separate columns in tidyverse?

My data using "dput(head(bites_hmis, 10)[, 1:30])":

```
structure(list(Province = c("1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", 
"1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", 
"1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province", "1 Koshi Province"
), District = c("101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", 
"101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", 
"101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG", "101 TAPLEJUNG"), Municipaltiy = c("10108 Sirijanga Rural Municipality", 
"10109 Sidingba Rural Municipality", "10107 Yangwarak Rural Municipality", 
"10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality", "10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality", 
"10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality", "10106 Phungling Municipality", 
"10106 Phungling Municipality", "10104 Maiwakhola Rural Municipality", 
"10106 Phungling Municipality"), Ward = c("10108 Sirijanga 02", 
"10109 Sidingba 03", "10107 Yangwarak 05", "10105 Aatharai Tribeni 05", 
"10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04", "10105 Aatharai Tribeni 02", "10106 Phungling 01", 
"10106 Phungling 02", "10104 Maiwakhola 02", "10106 Phungling 08"
), `Health Facility` = c("AMBEGUDIN HP TAPLEJUNG", "ANGKHOP HP TAPLEJUNG", 
"CHAKSIBOTE HP TAPLEJUNG", "CHANGE BHSC TAPLEJUNG", "CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG", 
"CHOKPUR HP TAPLEJUNG", "DANDAGAUN BHSC PHUNGLING 01 TAPLEJUNG", 
"DEULINGE BHSC TAPLEJUNG", "DHUNGESAGHU PHC TAPLEJUNG", "DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG"
), `Shrawan 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2), `Shrawan 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Bhadra 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), `Bhadra 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Ashwin 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Ashwin 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Kartik 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Kartik 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Mangsir 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Mangsir 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Poush 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
2, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), `Poush 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Magh 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Magh 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Falgun 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Falgun 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Chaitra 2071 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Chaitra 2071 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Baishak 2072 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Baishak 2072 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Jestha 2072 -Dog Bite` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1), `Jestha 2072 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Asar 2072 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), `Asar 2072 -Other Rabies Susceptible Animal Bite` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), `Shrawan 2072 -Dog Bite` = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bites_hmis |>
  pivot_longer(6:30, values_drop_na = TRUE) |>
  separate(name, c("Month", "Year", "Type"), sep = " ", extra = "merge")
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 9 × 9
  Province         District      Municipaltiy                              Ward                      `Health Facility`         Month   Year  Type     value
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>                                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
2 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     2
3 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Mangsir 2071  Dog Bite     1
4 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Poush   2071  Dog Bite     2
5 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Magh    2071  Dog Bite     1
6 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10104 Maiwakhola Rural Municipality       10104 Maiwakhola 02       DHUNGESAGHU PHC TAPLEJUNG Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     1
7 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
8 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Poush   2071  Dog Bite     1
9 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Jestha  2072  Dog Bite     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Directly using `pivot_longer`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   pivot_longer(!1:5, names_to = c("Month", "Year", "Type"), 
                names_pattern = "(\\w+)\\W+(\\w+)\\W+(.*)", 
                values_drop_na = TRUE)

# A tibble: 9 × 9
  Province         District      Municipaltiy                              Ward                      `Health Facility`         Month   Year  Type     value
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>                                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
2 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     2
3 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Mangsir 2071  Dog Bite     1
4 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Poush   2071  Dog Bite     2
5 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Magh    2071  Dog Bite     1
6 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10104 Maiwakhola Rural Municipality       10104 Maiwakhola 02       DHUNGESAGHU PHC TAPLEJUNG Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     1
7 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
8 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Poush   2071  Dog Bite     1
9 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Jestha  2072  Dog Bite     1
```

Comment: Better. I also searched for a pattern, but was not able to implement!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar way integrating both `separate` and `filter` into `pivot_longer()` at the cost of renaming first the column names to clearly separate with `-`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~str_replace_all(.x, 
                                     pattern = "(.*?)(\\d{4})(.*$)", 
                                     replacement = "\\1-\\2\\3")) %>% 
pivot_longer(
  cols = -c(Province, District, Municipaltiy, Ward, `Health Facility`),
  names_to = c("Month", "Year", "Type"),
  names_sep= " \\-", 
  values_drop_na = TRUE
)
```

```
  Province         District      Municipaltiy                              Ward                      `Health Facility`         Month   Year  Type     value
  <chr>            <chr>         <chr>                                     <chr>                     <chr>                     <chr>   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>
1 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
2 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     2
3 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Mangsir 2071  Dog Bite     1
4 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Poush   2071  Dog Bite     2
5 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10105 Aatharai Tribeni Rural Municipality 10105 Aatharai Tribeni 04 CHANGE HP TAPLEJUNG       Magh    2071  Dog Bite     1
6 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10104 Maiwakhola Rural Municipality       10104 Maiwakhola 02       DHUNGESAGHU PHC TAPLEJUNG Bhadra  2071  Dog Bite     1
7 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Shrawan 2071  Dog Bite     2
8 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Poush   2071  Dog Bite     1
9 1 Koshi Province 101 TAPLEJUNG 10106 Phungling Municipality              10106 Phungling 08        DOKHU HP TAPLEJUNG        Jestha  2072  Dog Bite     1
```